# javascript : Merge two arrays into one

Tags: javascript

Say for example I have an array

```
arr = [
 1, 2, 3
 4, 5, 6
]
```

Instead, I would like to use aliases for each line
Ex.

```
var a = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
var b = [ 4, 5, 6 ];
```

Where

```
arr = [
 a,
 b
]
```

should be the same as the original `arr`.

Yet the current example gives back `[ [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ]` instead

How would I achieve something like this in javascript?

Comment: Javascript is not a whitespace sensitive language, line breaks will not matter.

Comment: Didn't `arr = [
 a,
 b
]` work?

Comment: @thefourtheye `arr = [a, b]` results in `[ [1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`

Comment: @dk123 What exactly do you want? I couldn't understand that from the question. Can you please explain clearly with an example?

Comment: Please clarify "it isn't at the moment since I would be inserting arrays instead of actual numbers of lists"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Array::concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
var a = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
var b = [ 4, 5, 6 ];
var c = [ 7, 8, 9 ];

var arr = Array.concat(a,b,c);

alert(arr); // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ys2ow0y/1/

Answer (score 1):

**"should be the same as the original arr."** NO!!!

> The `concat()` method is used to join two or more arrays.
>
> This method does not change the existing arrays, but returns a new
>   array, containing the values of the joined arrays.

```
var a = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
var b = [ 4, 5, 6 ];

arr = a.concat(b); //or Array.concat(a,b);
console.log(a);//[1,2,3]
console.log(b);//[4,5,6]
console.log(arr);//[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```